# exist-db aborts tring to store well formed document

Tags: exist-db

I cannot store the following well formed XML document in the database. I originally encountered this trying to use store-file-from-pattern to store several documents. The document was not store and the command gave no feedback (that I could discern) that it was unsuccessful, I just noticed that some of the collections that were created were empty.

I have since tried to store the document by doing a put from the Java Admin Client. When doing so I get

Failed to invoke method parse in class org.exist.xmlrpc.RpcConnection: org.w3c.dom.DOMException: Too many element/attribute names registered in the database. No of distinct names is limited to 16bit. Aborting store.

Here is the document causing this.

```
<movies year="1888">
   <movie title="Pferd und Reiter Springen über ein Hindernis">
      <cinematographers>
         <person name="Ansarifar, Safa"/>
      </cinematographers>
      <directors>
         <person name="Ansari, Samim"/>
      </directors>
      <genres>
         <short/>
      </genres>
      <keywords>
         <tag name="1880s"/>
         <educational-film/>
         <horse/>
         <horse-jumping/>
         <horse-rider/>
         <horse-riding/>
         <military/>
         <prussia/>
         <riding-a-horse/>
      </keywords>
   </movie> 
</movies>
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a limit to the number of distinct element and attribute names you can have in an eXist symbol table. The limit was reached here and symbol tables do not appear to get flushed when the collection that caused the overflow is deleted.